# What does cls() function do inside a class method?

Tags: python, class

Today I'm viewing another's code, and saw this:

```
class A(B): 
    # Omitted bulk of irrelevant code in the class

    def __init__(self, uid=None):
        self.uid = str(uid)

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, uid):
        o = cls(uid)
        # Also Omitted lots of code here
```

what does this `cls()` function do here?

If I got some other classes inherit this `A` class, call it `C`, when calling this get method, would this `o` use `C` class as the caller of `cls()`?

Comment: `cls` is `A` in this case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For `classmethod`s, the first parameter is the class through which the class method is invoked with instead of the usual `self` for `instancemethod`s (which all methods in a class implicitly are unless specified otherwise).

Here's an example -- and for the sake of exercise, I added an exception that checks the identity of the `cls` parameter.

```
class Base(object):
    @classmethod
    def acquire(cls, param):
        if cls is Base:
            raise Exception("Must be called via subclass :(")
        return "this is the result of `acquire`ing a %r with %r" % (cls, param)

class Something(Base):
    pass

class AnotherThing(Base):
    pass

print Something.acquire("example")
print AnotherThing.acquire("another example")
print Base.acquire("this will crash")
```

---

```
this is the result of `acquire`ing a <class '__main__.Something'> with 'example'
this is the result of `acquire`ing a <class '__main__.AnotherThing'> with 'another example'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classmethod.py", line 16, in <module>
    print Base.acquire("this will crash")
  File "classmethod.py", line 5, in acquire
    raise Exception("Must be called via subclass :(")
Exception: Must be called via subclass :(
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question as to what ``cls()`` does in the classmethod he has seen. As I've stated (@classmethods aside) it's a factory.

Answer (score 34):

`cls` is the constructor function, it will construct class A and call the `__init__(self, uid=None)` function.

If you enherit it (with C), the cls will hold 'C', (and not A), see AKX answer.

Answer (score 18):

It's a class factory.

Essentially it the same as calling:

```
o = A(uid)
```

`cls` in `def get(...):` **is** `A`.

Comment: Feel free to suggest an improved edit. This is a community forum afterall.

Comment: There is a large amount of expected knowledge in this answer.