# cls vs. self vs. Class call in python

Tags: python, class, object, self

I am a beginner in Python, and using Lutz's book to understand `classmethod`, `staticmethod` and `instancemethod`. The objective of this code is to understand the difference among `cls`, `self`, and direct Class call (`Spam1.numInstances`) by counting number of instances created.

Here's an example derived from the book. I am unsure why parent class (`Spam1`) attribute (`numInstances`) doesn't increment when called through `Sub1` and `Other1`, which are child classes.

Here's my code:

```
class Spam1:
    numInstances = 0
    def count(cls):
        cls.numInstances += 1
        print("In count -> number of instances: cls, Spam", cls.numInstances, Spam1.numInstances)

    def __init__(self):
        print("-----")
        print("In init, before -> number of instances: self, Spam",self.numInstances,Spam1.numInstances )
        self.count()
        print("In init, after -> number of instances: self, Spam",self.numInstances,Spam1.numInstances )
        print("-----")

    count=classmethod(count)


class Sub1(Spam1):
    numInstances = 0

class Other1(Spam1):
    pass

a=Spam1() #Output after increment: 1,1,1 (self, cls, Spam1)
b=Spam1() #Output after increment: 2,2,2 (self, cls, Spam1)
c=Spam1() #Output after increment: 3,3,3 (self, cls, Spam1)
d=Sub1()  #Output after increment: 1,1,3 (self, cls, Spam1)
e=Sub1()  #Output after increment: 2,2,3 (self, cls, Spam1)
f=Other1() #Output after increment: 4,4,3 (self, cls, Spam1)
```

I have spent one day trying to debug this code, but I cannot understand how `cls.numInstances` works because PyCharm would show "no reference" for `cls.numInstances` in debug mode. Being frustrated, I read a few SO threads: [What does cls() function do inside a class method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24799403/what-does-cls-function-do-inside-a-class-method), [What is the 'cls' variable used for in Python classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613000/what-is-the-cls-variable-used-for-in-python-classes), and [Python - self, no self and cls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554738/python-self-no-self-and-cls), but I cannot understand what's going on.

Specifically, here are my questions:

**a) why is it that `Spam1.numInstances` doesn't increase when `d`, `e`, and `f` are created?**

Here's my attempt to answer this question:

*a.i) It is my understanding that `cls` is used to access class attributes. For `d` and `e`, `self.numInstances` is used to access instance attribute, which is zero because `Sub1` zeroes the value of inherited attribute `numInstances` from `Spam1`. `cls` accesses class attribute of `Sub1`, which is also the same as attribute of `Sub1` class. Hence, `self` and `cls` values we see in the output are of `Sub1` instance and class respectively. Is my understanding correct?*

*a.ii) `f` inherits `numInstances` from `Spam1`. Hence, `self.numInstances` and `cls.numInstances` of `f` take the value from `Spam1`. Their value is incremented but not of `Spam1` because `cls` refers to `Other1` and because `self` refers to `f`, which is the object of `Other1`. Hence, `Spam1`'s `numInstances` is never touched.*

**b) Is my understanding about the differences among `self.numInstances`, `cls.numInstances`, and `Spam1.numInstances` correct? If not, can someone please explain it?**

I believe that my question is very basic. I hope someone will help me out. I am lost.

Comment: It is important to understand that `self` and `cls` are merely conventional names here. They could be `foo` or `banana`. What makes them special is that they are the first argument, and thus they get implicitly passed the instance when called on the instance (and the class when you use the `classmethod` decorator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple misunderstandings here:

1. There is *never* an instance attribute named `numInstances` at any point in this code. `self.numInstances` *checks* for an instance attribute, but because nothing *assigns* to `self.numInstances`, there is no instance attribute to read, so accesses to `self.numInstances` end up reading the class attribute.
2. `f` doesn't exactly "inherit" the parent class's value. When `cls.numInstances += 1` is executed, it tries to look up `Other1.numInstances`, finds it doesn't exist, and checks superclasses, eventually finding `Spam1.numInstances`. It increments that value, then assigns back to `Other1.numInstances` (`+=` in Python always reassigns even if it does the work in place, and for immutable `int`, the work is *not* in place); in the future, accesses to `Other1.numInstances` won't check for `Spam1.numInstances`, as `Other1`'s attribute now exists.

Answer (score 1):

When you are working with instances of `Sub1`, `Spam1`'s `numInstances` attribute is inaccessible (other than by explicitly writing `Spam1.numInstances`); `cls` in `count()` refers to `Sub1`, and the attribute is found in that class, so there is no need to look further up the inheritance chain.

When you are working with instances of `Other1`, the initial read of `numInstances` does come from `Spam1` - but as soon as you assign a value, that goes into `Other1` (because `cls` is `Other1` now), and all further references to that name now find that instead of `Spam1`'s version.

There are three distinct class attributes named `numInstances` in your code: two that exist as soon as the classes `Spam1` and `Sub1` are defined, and one that exists after the first instance of `Other1` is created.